# "using namespace" for defining global functions

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

When defining class member functions in the source file, we can use `using namespace ns1::ns2::...::nsx` to avoid having to fully qualify function names.

E.g.

```
// Header file - foo.hpp
namespace ns1::ns2 {
    class FooClass {
        void fooMethod();
    }
}

// Source file - foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
using namespace ns1::ns2;
void FooClass::fooMethod() {
    // do something
}
```

However, I recently got into a confusion when trying to define a global function.

See the following example.

```
// Header file - bar.hpp
namespace ns1::ns2{
    void barFunction();  // <-- compile error: undefined reference
}

// Source file - bar.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"
using namespace ns1::ns2;
void barFunction(){
    // do something
}
```

I was expecting the compiler to deduce the definition in `bar.cpp` to be the definition of `ns1::ns2::barFunction` defined in `bar.hpp`. But it doesn't do that. (Everything works fine if I use the fully qualified name in the definition).

Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is as expected - your understanding is wrong.   `using namespace ns1::ns2` does not cause a subsequent definition of `barFunction()` to be in namespace `ns1::ns2`.    It means that existing names in `ns1::ns2` become candidates to match names used in `barFunction()`.

Comment: You can use two or more `using` together: `using namespace foo; using namespace bar;`; which namespace should be `barFunction()`? The `using namespace <someNamespace>` directive cause that when you use a symbol, the symbol is looked **also** in all namespace used; not that a definition is places in the used namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behavior.

> **[namespace.udir]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#3) A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative
>   region in which it appears.

This means there is no declaration for `barFunction` in the global namespace at the point you define it. And that makes the definition the first and only declaration of such a function (in the global namespace).

This is by design, because a using directive can often bring in way more names than expected. So not having it trample the declarative region it appears in is good.